# inputAccessoryView not getting touch events on iPhone X

Tags: ios, autolayout, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide, inputaccessoryview

I have a view that I assign as the `inputAccessoryView` of my view controller. I adjusted the constraints so that it's above the home indicator on iPhone X (X, XR, XS, XS Max). I keep that `inputAccessoryView` pinned to the bottom of the screen when the keyboard is hidden by setting `canBecomeFirstResponder` to `true` in my view controller.

It works on all phones except for the X family. On all of the X phones, my view is not getting any touch events - they are hitting the view below it, as if `inputAccessoryView` wasn't there.

[image: Tapping any of the buttons inside inputAccessoryView won't work]

If I constrain the bottom to superview instead of safeArea, it works, but then it's too close to the home indicator, which I don't want:

[image: inputAccessoryView is too close to the home indicator]

In this [radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/34411433) ("inputAccessoryViews should respect safe area inset with external keyboard on iPhone X"), Apple engineers say that this is not a bug and that developers should constrain one of the views to its parent's `safeAreaLayoutGuide`:

> Engineering has provided the following feedback regarding this issue: It’s your responsibility to respect the input accessory view’s safeAreaInsets. We designed it this way so developers could provide a background view (i.e., see Safari’s Find on Page input accessory view) and lay out the content view with respect to safeAreaInsets. This is fairly straightforward to accomplish. Have a view hierarchy where you have a container view and a content view. The container view can have a background color or a background view that encompasses its entire bounds, and it lays out it’s content view based on safeAreaInsets. If you’re using autolayout, this is as simple as setting the content view’s bottomAnchor to be equal to it’s superview’s safeAreaLayoutGuide.

I believe that's exactly what I'm doing, but I'm clearly missing something since it breaks on X.

GitHub project is here: https://github.com/nambatee/HorizontallyScrollableToolbarAccessoryView/tree/master/Horizontally%20Scrollable%20Toolbar%20Accessory%20View

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is actually is that you are not setting a height for `inputAccessoryView` and your scrollView is out of bounds that's why you are not getting the touch events and just to prove that if you go to your top level view and set it to clips to bounds and run your project this is what you get
[image: sample]

So why is this happening? it's because you view is not having an `intrinsicContentSize` you can give it an `intrinsicContentSize` by subclassing `UIView` and override `intrinsicContentSize` and return what ever width and height you want just like this

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize.zero
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set your view to be CustomView in code and in the nib file

```
private lazy var horizontallyScrollableToolbarAccessoryView: CustomView? = {
        let nibName = "HorizontallyScrollableToolbarAccessoryView"
        let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? CustomView
        return view
}()
```

you can also provide the height through a height constraint like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.horizontallyScrollableToolbarAccessoryView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}
```

but you will still need to set your `intrinsicContentSize` to be `CGSize.Zero`

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize.zero
    }
}
```

and that's what you get at the end a working `scrollView`

[image: sample 2]

Comment: I wonder how much time would take me to figure this out by myself. Thanks for this!